# Checking work for exercise 1.14, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (J.M. Lee, 2/e)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Here's the exercise:

> **Exercise [Lee, 1.14].** Prove the following lemma. Suppose $\mathcal{X}$ is a locally finite  collection of a topological space $M$. Then:
>
> (a) The collection $\{\overline{X} : X \in \mathcal{X}\}$ is locally finite.
>
> (b) $\overline{\cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} X} = \cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} \overline{X}$.

Here's my work.

For part (a), if $U \subset M$ is open then $U \cap X= \emptyset$ implies $U \cap \overline{X} = \emptyset$. Indeed, if not, then as $U$ is open, to $p \in U \cap \overline{X}$ is associated $q \in U \cap X$, which contradicts $U \cap X = \emptyset$. Hence to general $p \in M$, if $p \in U_p \subset M$ is an open neighborhood of $p$, then $U_p \cap X$ is disjoint whenever $U_p \cap \overline{X}$ is disjoint, giving the claim.

For part (b), certainly $X \subset \cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} X$ for all $X \in \mathcal{X}$. Taking closures on both sides, and passing to the union on the left hand side implies $\cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} \overline{X} \subset \overline{\cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} X}$. Conversely, if $p \not \in \cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} \overline{X}$, then there is an open neighborhood $p \in U_p \subset M$ such that the only sets $X \in \mathcal{X}$ that $U_p$ intersects nontrivially with are $X_1, \dots, X_n \in \mathcal{X}$. Let $\widetilde{U} = U \setminus (\overline{X_1} \cup \cdots \cup \overline{X_n})$. By construction $p \in \widetilde{U}$ and $\widetilde{U}$ is open. Additionally, if $\widetilde{U} \cap \overline{X} = \emptyset$ for $X \in \mathcal{X}$, $X \neq X_k$, $k = 1, \dots, n$, since $\widetilde{U} \cap \overline{X} \subset U_p \cap \overline{X} = \emptyset$ for such $X$. Hence, $\cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} \overline{X}$ is closed, which implies $ \cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} \overline{X} \supset \overline{\cup_{X \in \mathcal{X}} X}$, as needed.